# Inserting attribute from property (CoreData) using multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, data-retrieval

I'm having a problem with finding a solution how to pass the info from an attribute that is saved in one view controller -> `NSManagedObject` into a label that is located in another `UIViewController`. The issue is that it says it can't convert it to String....and I thought there's going to be a simple GET function but so far couldn't find anything

Edit: NOTE - I am doing the saving in  `UIViewControllerACCOUNT` and wish to call the data in the `UIViewControllerSETTINGS`

![left UIVcont = save. right UIViewCont = call -> format label]:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjNo2.png

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Account")

    //3
    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?


    if fetchedResults != nil {
```

// HERE i want the code to insert the data from CoreData into the label. For example the data from the Entity Account with the  attribute "name" into the NameLabel... If i do something like

let account = fetchRequest.valueForKey("name") as String  ---> Ends up throwing error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
            NameLabel.text = account

```
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

How do i pass the info from CoreData - Entity.attribute -> Label.text ?

Edit: When i try to set it it says `[NSObject: AnyObject] is not convertible to 'String'`
Edit 2: The attributes (name, age, ...) are all set to String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchedResults` returned by the `executeFetchRequest` is an array (even if there is one - or no - objects matching the fetch request).  So you need first to extract the individual NSManagedObjects from the array.  Assuming you want the first item (index 0), you could use:

```
    if let resultsArray = fetchedResults {
        if resultsArray.count > 0 {
            let myAccount = resultsArray[0] as NSManagedObject
            nameLabel.text = myAccount.valueForKey("name") as String?
            // Likewise for the other labels
        } else {
            println("No results from fetch request.")
        }
    }
```

If your `Account` entity is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, then you can replace `NSManagedObject` in line 3 with `Account`.

Comment: Is there a workaround wrapper that enables the action like done in this video at 21:30 mark (https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_2946208203&feature=iv&src_vid=K6PfveuxUEk&v=Fv-A8lKn7VY)? 

I think it's kind of silly to not be able to directly call an attribute value and instead search for it using key values..

Comment: Yes.  As per the last line of my answer, you need to create subclasses of NSManagedObject for your entities.  If you locate the video for Part 1 of the above tutorial, he goes through the necessary steps at around 13:30 mark.  That will enable you to use the dot notation to access the attributes.